# Не видно кнопку Unity

Tags: unity3d

При добавлении кнопки на канвас её не видно, я так понимаю дело в слоях.
Как настроить это дело? Я дико извиняюсь, только начал делать шаги в Unity.
[image: Не видно кнопки]

Comment: Здравствуйте, при воспроизведении (нажатии кнопки Play) кнопку тоже не видно?

Если не видно, то сделайте скриншот окна Inspector для button.

Если видно, то все в порядке. Вы можете двойным щелчком по button сфокусироваться на объекте и редактировать его. (Canvac расположен немножко в другой области редактирования, - это нормально)

PS: Обычно Canvac делают самостоятельным объектом, а не дочерним от Main Camera, как у вас.

Comment: Редактировать я его могу, да только не видно адекватно кнопку. Наблюдаю все те же "чертежи" из черных векторов. Как сделать canvas самостоятельным? Или может скинете пример как налепить это дело правильно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорей всего, вы изменили `DrawMode` окошка `Scene`. Что бы вернуть на вариант "по умолчанию" поменяйте его на `Shaded`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ты мой спаситель, благодарен бесконечно вечно, спасибо!